How is the privileges list made?
I noticed that privileges here on our website can be acquired with a significant lower score than on other SE sites (ex: a trusted user at StackOverflow or Superuser requires 20000 reputation while here it only requires 2000).
So how are these values defined? Do they change when beta ends?

On private beta sites, some privileges require less rep than they do on public beta sites, and ditto for public beta sites versus graduated sites. So, for instance, where anyone can now create a new tag, you'll need 150 after the site goes public, and 300 after the site launches. What rep is required to do what can be found on the FAQ and on the list of privileges, but as a help it's posted below.
Don't be surprised when this happens—yes, you may lose some privileges when the site shifts from private to pubic beta. The only way to restore lost privileges is to keep asking great questions and writing great answers (and voting. Always vote. You have 30 votes a day. Use them, please).
How do we get people here to have higher reputation scores? Keep voting up those good questions and answers, that's how. Edit questions and answers into shape when they need it, so that others will vote them up. And please, don't forget to vote on questions. 
(PS: you get up to an extra ten question votes per day if you vote on enough questions, too)

Table of reps and privileges:
                                      Where you'll be shortly 
                                 Where you are now ↴        ↓
Action                                     Private ß Public ß Launched     SO
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Ask and answer questions                           1        1        1      1
Ask and answer questions on meta                   5        5        5    N/A
Skip lecture on how to ask                       N/A      N/A      N/A     10
Add images, 2+ link, answer protected questions    1       10       10     10
Create community wiki answers                     10       10       10     10
Vote up                                            1       15       15     15
Flag posts                                        15       15       15     15
Talk in chat                                      20       20       20     20
Comment everywhere                                 1       50       50     50
Set bounties                                      75       75       75     75
Create chat rooms                                100      100      100    100
Edit community wiki w/o approval                   1      100      100    100
Vote down (-1 rep on answers)                      1      125      125    125
Vote in moderator elections                      N/A      N/A      150    150
One time +100 rep to all linked accounts         200      200      200    200
Reduced advertisements                           200      200      200    200
View close votes                                   1      250      250    250
Vote to close, reopen, or migrate own questions    1      250      250    250
Nominate for moderator                           N/A      N/A      300    300
Create new tags                                    1      150      300   1500
Retag questions                                    1      200      500    500
Show total up and down vote counts               100      750     1000   1000
Create a gallery chat room                      1000     1000     1000   1000
Edit other's posts w/o approval                  500     1000     2000   2000
Approve or reject other's edits                  500     1000     2000   2000
Suggest tag synonyms                            1250     1250     2500   2500
Vote to close, reopen, or migrate questions        1      500     3000   3000
Approve tag wiki edits                           750     1500     5000   5000
Access moderation tools                         1000     2000      10K    10K
Reduce captchas                                 1000     2000      10K    10K
Review chat flags                                10K      10K      10K    10K
Protect questions                               1750     3500      15K    15K
Trusted user                                    2000     4000      20K    20K
Painting of unicorns, signed by Jeff and Joel                     200K   200K


Thanks for the table. I so want a painting of unicorns! It definitely beats any other privilege ;)
